# Can https server load several different certs with openssl?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

Can https server load several different certs with openssl, and all client with different certs can communicate with the same server with the same port?

I'm digging openssl library, but it seems like when server starts, it can only use one cert.pem and one keyfile.

How can I load multiple certs and keyfiles, so that when a client with different cert send a request, the same server can go through all the certs it loads and give the correct response?